# How to programatically create an image from other images?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, png, pixel

I have almost 200 images (`.png` files) that I want to assemble together into one PNG file. All the image files have the same dimensions (705 x 1000).
I want to make 20 rows of 10 images each row, with 10 pixels horizontally between each image and 10 pixels between each row.

How can I do this programmatically? Can this be done with Python? Can I avoid having to do this manually using a word-processing or other other office style program?

Comment: I would suggest giving us some code on what you have already tried. If you don't know where to start, I would suggest googling something like `append png files into one file` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I did some Googling and found my answer.

The Pillow Python package is exactly what I was looking for.

It can merge images as such:

```
from PIL import Image

def merge(im1, im2):
    w = im1.size[0] + im2.size[0]
    h = max(im1.size[1], im2.size[1])
    im = Image.new("RGBA", (w, h))

    im.paste(im1)
    im.paste(im2, (im1.size[0], 0))

    return im
```

(taken from [Official Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html))

This is enough to get me started!

Answer (score 1):

With **ImageMagick** in Terminal, using:

```
magick montage *.png -tile 10x20 -geometry +10+10 result.png
```

---

If Python is a hard requirement, which doesn't seem to be the case from your question, you can use [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) which is a Python binding to **ImageMagick**.